# Dynamic Invoicing/Receipt Reporting tools for Android?

Tags: android, reporting-services, crystal-reports, itext

I m a Doctor ,(Ophthalmic) i.e Eye Surgeon learning Android Online out of interest, This is my second question on Stack Overflow & I realize that this is one of the most efficient way of not getting stuck and learn from experienced developers & Move Ahead So thank yo SO.

My Last Question was about android so is this one.

I m making a simple application on mobile in which user is going to store his inventory & client details. Now the next requirement is the user should be able to generate invoices/prescriptions from the application itself.

When i made this application for Desktop using Java & Swing , I had used Jasper Reports to dynamically pass Data from J-Table & Other parameters usin a hashmap and passing it to the jrxml design template which i designed using ireport Designer ***community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer***.

I want to do the same for android, not that i did not search or try something before asking a question up here. I couldn't find much documentation & Tutorials to do so.

I m new to SO , hence i don't have enough reputation to insert more than 2 links in the questions this i m marking the links bold & italic to be viewed and explored.

This ***stackoverflow.com/questions/8890340/android-what-are-the-good-reporting-tools-to-design-and-generate-reports-from*** Question on SO is asking the same thing.
The answer to it is itext & generation of reports over server.

**So can we use itext the same way in android as we used in java SE applications ?**

Also i have found other alternatives like

- itextG : ***itextpdf.com/product/itextg***
- Jaspersoft Mobile - Android Sdk :  ***community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspermobile-android***

  Regarding itextG or itext-core i did not find too much other one video on youtube and simple documentation but that i guess is just a PDF creating tool, couldn't find any tutorials on it.
  **Please help me  if you find anything more on it.**

& Regarding Jaspersoft Mobile, If m not wrong says it uses Jasper Server for creating reports etc. which means its again network dependent so it is time consuming as well as one cannot generate reports offline ?

But I m sure there are solutions available because there are android applications available in market which are generating reports taking data from SQlite. Until and unless they are native apps there is a solution , Please someone help me out with what it is.

The apps on the store are

- [Invoice2go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.invoice2go.invoice2goplus&hl=en)
- [Invoice Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aadhk.woinvoice&hl=en)

& Invoice Maker is Remarkably Fast & Effective.

So Summarizing the long story short

- Are there an easy to use offline reporting tools available for android and ios development with documentation & Tutorials to follow ?
- Can we itext simply the same way we use it in Java applications?

---

Comment: I would tread very lightly in this direction if I were you. While it's admirable that you're learning to do this on your own, especially in the direction of making your regular job better via automation, there are a number of concerns I have about this. For one, information security. Since you are a doctor, and your application intends to handle client data and prescription information, does it do enough to fall under HIPAA requirements for information security? I am not a lawyer, but this is probably something you should have a lawyer look into before you progress further.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja I m just learning this out of interest as i never got a chance to learn software and was one of my fascinations to code. I m not making this to automate my clinic. It's just fun learning and spend some time productively at night.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new standard for e-invoices. It's called ZUGFeRD and you can find more about it [here](http://itextpdf.com/book/zugferdthefutureofinvoicing-preview.pdf). As you can see, there is a whole book in the works on how to create invoices with iText. The book isn't finished yet (although you may get an unrevised draft if you mail iText Group directly), but the examples can already by consulted [here](https://github.com/itext/sandbox/tree/master/src/main/java/zugferd).

The idea is that you implement one of the following interfaces:

- [`BasicProfile`](https://github.com/itext/pdfa/blob/master/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/zugferd/profiles/BasicProfile.java)
- [`ComfortProfile`](https://github.com/itext/pdfa/blob/master/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/zugferd/profiles/ComfortProfile.java)

If you implement the Basic profile, you can create the ZUGFeRD XML automatically, but you still have to write code to create your invoice. If you implement the Comfort profile, the ZUGFeRD XML contains all the necessary info to create the invoice. In chapter 5 of the book, we convert the XML to HTML using XSL. In chapter 6 of the book, we convert that HTML to PDF. That's a very powerful way to create invoices that (1) are future proof, (2) can be accessed by machines in an EDI context, and (3) are accessible for the blind and the visually impaired (Section 508).

iTextG is an Android port of iText. If you have iText code to create invoices in a Java environment, you can use the same code with iTextG. However: I would never create invoices on a mobile device. I would have the mobile device connect to a server where the invoices are created in a secure way.

Comment: Firstly @BrunoLowagie thanks for your references. I will definitely go through them and get back with doubts if any. Also online generation of reports is a good idea but if at times the server is down the work will stop so i want to learn the off line way too. **Are you sure we can use i-text the same way as in Java Environment ?**   Is there any documentation for the same to use with mobile ?

Comment: What would be the difference between an iText and an iTextG code sample? Did you browse [iTextG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itextg) questions?

Comment: Sir give me a days time , i ll study about the library from sources i can find and get back to you with my queries.

Comment: @Dr.AmitJain So? Did you succeed with your app? What approach did you take?